# GZIP does not accept fileStream

Tags: java, gzip

```
String inFileName = testDoc.gz;

File inFile = new File(inFileName);
System.out.println(inFileName);
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(fileStream);
```

When executing the above code in the the last line returns the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
```

I have tried it with multiple documents and cannot see the problem.

**EDIT: The documents were not created by me, they are downloaded.  They are in the .gz format and by multiple documents I mean different .gz files.**

Comment: By multiple documents do you mean multiple gzipped documents?

Comment: I recommend you try un-gzipping some of these documents with a gzip utility first, to confirm they are actually valid before you start chasing a code defect that may not exist.

Comment: @Jim Tough How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Get a utility (such as WinRAR if you're using a Windows machine) that can decompress .gzip or .gz files. If the utility says the files are not valid then your code is not the problem.

Comment: I've unzipped the files in the OS and they are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try mounting the GZIP file with [VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html#gzip%20and%20bzip2).

Answer (score 0):

GZIPInputStream works with GZIP files, decompressing the input. GZIPOutputStream compressed whatever you write to it. So if you want to compress data, then you must write to a GZIPOutputStream.

To compress a file, read with with a FileInputStream and wrap a FileOutputStream with a GZIPOutputStream; read from the input file into a buffer, write the buffer to the GZIPOutputStream, until you're done and then close the GZIPOutputStream.

To decompress the data you can read it with a GZIPInputStream. I just checked it and it works; compressed a file with gzip on the command-line and read it with a GZIPInputStream (wrapped around a FileInputStream).

Comment: I'm very sorry but I don't understand. Are you saying I need to rewrite the .gz file as a GZIPOutputStream then re-read it as a GZIPIputStream?

Comment: Bizarre answer. Doesn't answer the question.